# iMessage issue contacts

Tags: iphone

Why does my iMessage display, "other + (the number) 
Example: [image]

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that either you do not have this phone number in your contacts so the default for an unknown number is **other** or if you look at the phone number in your contacts for this person, you have the phone number set to other.

There are several descriptions, home, work, iPhone, etc. You are able to set these in contacts.